# Will Lion install MySQL with it?

Tags: macos, mysql

I had MAMP running on my laptop. I use MySQL a lot. I kinda messed with the user file permission and I fixed it , in that process I changed some password in MySQL config files. So now SQL does not work even though MAMP runs perfectly.

I was planing on installing OS X Lion. I am wondering if upgrading to Lion will install MySQL and all its packages? Will it fix the problem? Or should I have to reinstall MySQL even after I upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to reset the root MySql password, [there's a guide on how to it on HowToForge.](http://www.howtoforge.com/reset-forgotten-mysql-root-password) You only need to have it happen once, back up the config files *before* tinkering with them

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe Lion comes with any sort of SQL server pre-installed.

Comment: oh ok. So can you suggest a way to fix this ? when I start MAMP both SQL and APACHE lights turn green ,but cant access SQL or create tables n stuffs.

Comment: `brew install postgresql` ([Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/))

Comment: Try re-installing MAMP.